# Rviz fuerte and master electric

Tags: rviz, macos, topic, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a robot which is running ROS electric.
On my macbook pro instead I have compiled Rviz fuerte (under osx Lion).

I set the ROS_MASTER on my mac and I'm able to communicate with the ROS Master.
Now on rViz I'm can read all the topics (so I see the robot moving, the laser scans and so on). I can also read the topics by means of `rostopic echo`.

However I can't write on topics.
More in details:

- When I send a 2D nav goal from Lion I can see the message with `rostopic` on my mac but not on the robot.
- If I try to send a 2D nav goal from ubuntu in virtual machine (still on my mac) I can see the message with `rostopic` on the robot by not on Lion.

Is it a known bug?
Or isn't possible to have rviz (fuerte) working with rosmaster (electric)?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36034/rviz-fuerte-and-master-electric/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This probably is neither a bug nor a problem with Fuerte vs. Electric. To me it looks like something is wrong with your network configuration. Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) wiki page for diagnosing this kind of issues.

Since the robot cannot receive any data from your laptop, I guess its host name is not known to the robot, i.e. `ping <hostname of your laptop>` doesn't work on your robot. Try setting the environment ROS_IP on your laptop.

Sending data from the virtual machine is even more tricky. You'll probably have to set up bridging instead of a routing based network. When you can ping the IP of your virtual machine from your robot and you set ROS_IP inside it, then publishing from it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-06-08**:
@Lorenz Thanks! Now it works. I forgot to update the IP of my macbook on the robot. So that was the problem. The virtual machine worked well already. As you said you have to bridge the connection to the virtual machine!